# Saving data from google spreadsheet to javascript readable variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, variables, save

Main goal: Create a javascript that **is independent of google spreadsheet** with critical data. Later this script should be a function on a website.

I have data from an approx 30*5000 size google spreadsheet range.

My javascript (makro in googlesheets) reads this data and assigns it to an array=myarray.

Problems

1. The read of data takes about 2000ms
2. The javascript is dependent on the spreadsheet.

So how can I make this myarray of data to be stored in my javascript permanently?

(Obviously whitout having to type or copy paste in 150K data manually)

I am not interested in cookies.

Comment: Your question is not clear: 1. what is done in the "read" that it takes 2 seconds? we can guess but it will not be productive... 2. what do you mean by "stored in my javascript"? JS is not a storage. Please clarify!

Comment: Copy the data into a file? Use that instead?

Comment: Nir Alfasi;  1) It is the for loop of the 30x5000 range that takes time. According to my timestamps,   2) let array= (data1,data2,.....data150k) is in my opionion a kind of information that is stored in the javascript code.

Comment: evoluionxbox :  Well yes. That is what the question is all about. Store it as big data variable in the javascript or in a file that the script can use if this is better. But How?